# How to query all users with Parse Javascript API

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using Node.js to automate some of maintainance for my Parse app, and I'm having problems with requesting all of the User account data. I'm able to request the information when using the REST API but not when using the Javascript SDK.

Here is the code:

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;

Parse.initialize(PARSE_APP_ID, PARSE_JAVASCRIPT_KEY, PARSE_MASTER_KEY);

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

query.find({
  success: function (results) {
    console.log(results);
},
  error: function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't clear from their documentation, but you have to use the Cloud SDK to even when you are not making requests from Cloud Code. If you look at their Javascript API Documentation, you can see this

**"Available in Cloud Code and Node.js only."**

To fix the issue, I had to add `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` to the above example.
Here is the complete code.

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;

Parse.initialize(PARSE_APP_ID, PARSE_JAVASCRIPT_KEY, PARSE_MASTER_KEY);
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

query.find({
  success: function (results) {
    console.log(results);
},
  error: function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```